# Nvidia Optimus GPU with Bumblebee Overclocking

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a laptop with Nvidia GT 640m LE GPU, with optimus. I already made it work with Bumblebee using optirun command, but I wanted to Overclock it since the nvidia's kepler chipset has a very good overclock potential. 
I already tried to enable nvidia-settings coolbits option, changing both X11/xorg.conf and bumblebee/xorg.conf with the "Coolbits" "1". But doesn't show the overclocking option at nvidia-settings. Does anyone know how to make it work ?